# Get rid of ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I've been working on this project for quite some time and I'm almost finished fixing up everything except one thing: memory leaks from viewcontrollers.

Here is my situation : I start in the main root view controller and navigate through VC's(root -> Levels -> Level1) like this

```
Level1* level1 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Level1"];
[self presentViewController:level1 animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This works fine and all but when I use this way to switch between 2 VC's multiple times, I create the new VC every time and the initial one does not get destroyed.

For example, I'm in level1 VC, decide to go to Upgrades VC, therefore using the methods from above. In my hierarchy of VC's, level1 is still alive when I'm in Upgrades scene. When I go back to the level1 scene, a new one is created with the old one still alive!

Now repeat this process several times and I can find myself with quite a few scenes of level1 VC and Upgrades VC stacked up because the initial VC doesn't get destroyed.

I thought of 2 fixes to this problem: Either I somehow destroy old VC's, which I don't know how, or use a navigation controller, which I don't know how either. I'd really prefer to do it the first way, because with a navigation controller, I fear I have to change quite a lot of stuff on how I navigate through controllers.

What I tried:

```
[self removeFromParentViewController];
```

Didn't do anything. I also tried to point the old view to nil( and all properties) once the new view was up, but this did nothing either. My VC's are still alive. If I try to point the view to nil before presenting the new VC, then I get this and a black screen :

Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Edit: I forgot to mention, I'm using ARC so I can't just dealloc stuff and all my views and VC's are done through coding, nothing in storyboard except for 2 things: In the storyboard, I put the VC in landscape mode, what class it inherits from and its storyboard ID

Comment: Do you ever call `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`?

Comment: how can you return in your VC1? using dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: or anything else?

Comment: I tried using it the way Ty_ told me to, but it doesn't work. That line of code actually takes me back to the previous VC